# How to select latest event table?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a site with events. I will have tables like this: event1, event2, event3.
Every week I will have another event.

How can I tell mysql to always select the latest event (if there are event1,2,3 then select event 3 only).

There will be some other tables in the database not only events.

Comment: Do you have any date or auto incremented ID column in event table?

Comment: Yes i have autoincremented ID

Comment: When asking questions relating to SQL queries, please provide the table structure. You can print out your table's structure by running the command `show create table your_table_name;`

Comment: Just to be clear, this is probably not a good table architecture to use, as it will break any possible referential integrity between the events and any other tables that reference an event record.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated to reflect that Tables are being dynamically created.

```
mysql> select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME like 'events_';
+------------+
| TABLE_NAME |
+------------+
| events1    |
| events2    |
| events3    |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME like 'events_' order by TABLE_NAME desc limit 1;
+------------+
| TABLE_NAME |
+------------+
| events3    |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: Ok but I want to select the table itself not the table contents. I have tables like this: event1, event2, event3. I want to select always the latest event (the one that has the highest number in its title).